# Totally Blocking Spam To Gmail Account

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I originally posted this query elsewhere but it was suggested to me that this was a more appropriate community.

We use a number of Gmail accounts for emergencies (e.g. issues with in-house email server) for the support staff. However we are getting an increasing amount of spam (dating sites, credit cards, loans, etc.). Blocking the sender results in the emails going into the spam folder which means manually deleting them to avoid accidentally deleting a valid email (via a block delete) that has gone into the spam folder.

Is there a way of fully blocking them so they do not even get as far as the spam folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create filter that deletes the unwanted emails from specific senders.

Click the cog wheel → *Settings → Filters and blocked addresses → Create a new filter*.

In the *From* field, enter `from:(offendingsender1@domain1.com OR offendingsender2@domain2.com OR offendingsender3@domain3.com)` ... you get the idea, first `from:(`, then list all offending addresses separated by `OR`, finish with a `)`.

Test the search expression by clicking the search button - this will close the settings dialog, and list all matching messages. Make sure the messages shown are those you want to delete, and nothing else. To go back to filter creation, click the *More* button → *Create filter*.

Click *Create filter with this search*, select *When a message arrives that matches this search: **Delete it***.

Click *Create filter*, and you're done - offending incoming messages will now be deleted directly.

Comment: The only problem I am having in setting up the filters is that I cannot seem to be able to use wild cards in the address (e.g. *@grot.com) or title (*Viagra*). It would also be useful to be able to use the known as name (e.g.PPI Claims).

Comment: You don't have to insert wildcards, just search for the substrings. At least for `from` searches, the following works: `from:(@domain1.com OR @domain2.com)`. And `subject:(viagra)` matches any message that contains `viagra` in the subject line.